# How to configure Ambari server and HDP applications using hostname with loopback IP address?

Tags: hadoop, ambari

I have an up and running Ambari server and HDP applications on a Ubuntu 12.04 with hostname resolved to a Public IP address.
I have a task to replace the public IP address with the loopback address. For that I did following changes:

1) Updated /etc/hosts file as:
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    127.0.0.1       mynode.com mynode
     #10.xx.xx.xx    mynode.com mynode

2) Set the values of following parameters to "0.0.0.0" to make it
 multi-homed    dfs.namenode.rpc-bind-host,
 dfs.namenode.servicerpc-bind-host, dfs.namenode.http-bind-host,
 dfs.namenode.https-bind-host, yarn.resourcemanager.bind-host,
 yarn.nodemanager.bind-host, yarn.timeline-service.bind-host,
 mapreduce.jobhistory.bind-host

After these changes, when I restarted the system, HDP applications are not coming up.

When I revert the changes done in /etc/hosts file to assign the public IP, it again starts working fine.

May I know what else I am missing?

I am seeing following errors in the ambari-server.log file:

> ERROR [alert-event-bus-2] AlertReceivedListener:365 - Unable to
>   process alert namenode_webui for an invalid service HDFS and component
>   NAMENODE on host localhost    ERROR [alert-event-bus-2]
>   AlertReceivedListener:365 - Unable to process alert
>   upgrade_finalized_state for an invalid service HDFS and component
>   NAMENODE on host localhost   ERROR [alert-event-bus-2]
>   AlertReceivedListener:365 - Unable to process alert
>   kafka_broker_process for an invalid service KAFKA and component
>   KAFKA_BROKER on host localhost    ERROR [alert-event-bus-2]
>   AlertReceivedListener:365 - Unable to process alert
>   storm_supervisor_process for an invalid service STORM and component
>   SUPERVISOR on host localhost    ERROR [alert-event-bus-2]
>   AlertReceivedListener:365 - Unable to process alert
>   storm_server_process for an invalid service STORM and component
>   STORM_UI_SERVER on host localhost    ERROR [alert-event-bus-2]
>   AlertReceivedListener:365 - Unable to process alert
>   hive_metastore_process for an invalid service HIVE and component
>   HIVE_METASTORE on host localhost    ERROR [alert-event-bus-2]
>   AlertReceivedListener:365 - Unable to process alert
>   mapreduce_history_server_process for an invalid service MAPREDUCE2 and
>   component HISTORYSERVER on host localhost    ERROR [alert-event-bus-2]
>   AlertReceivedListener:365 - Unable to process alert
>   ams_metrics_collector_process for an invalid service AMBARI_METRICS
>   and component METRICS_COLLECTOR on host localhost    ERROR
>   [alert-event-bus-2] AlertReceivedListener:365 - Unable to process
>   alert yarn_resourcemanager_webui for an invalid service YARN and
>   component RESOURCEMANAGER on host localhost    ERROR
>   [alert-event-bus-2] AlertReceivedListener:365 - Unable to process
>   alert hive_server_process for an invalid service HIVE and component
>   HIVE_SERVER on host localhost    ERROR [alert-event-bus-2]
>   AlertReceivedListener:365 - Unable to process alert storm_drpc_server
>   for an invalid service STORM and component DRPC_SERVER on host
>   localhost    ERROR [alert-event-bus-2] AlertReceivedListener:365 -
>   Unable to process alert ams_metrics_collector_autostart for an invalid
>   service AMBARI_METRICS and component METRICS_COLLECTOR on host
>   localhost    ERROR [alert-event-bus-2] AlertReceivedListener:365 -
>   Unable to process alert secondary_namenode_process for an invalid
>   service HDFS and component SECONDARY_NAMENODE on host localhost

Any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the `127.0.0.1 mynode.com mynode` line in your hosts file. That line is overriding the localhost line. Notice how all the errors say "on host localhost"

Comment: Thanks. After merging the two lines in the /etc/hosts, it worked.        127.0.0.1 localhost mynode.com mynode

Comment: Alright, cool. I'll answer with that.

Comment: Thanks a lot once again for your help.

Comment: You can use the checkmark next to the answer below to accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having these as separate lines seems to be the problem.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 mynode.com mynode
```

You can either remove the second line (because it is overriding the first), but making them one line is recommended

```
127.0.0.1 localhost mynode.com mynode
```